# cant cast ModifiedDocument from FindAndModify in MongoDb CSharp

Tags: mongodb

The code below works, but clearly the last two lines are "hacky."  This is the only thing I've gotten to work so far:

```
var collection = _database.GetCollection<KeyValueDocument>(KeyValueDocumentCollectionName);

var query = Query.And(Query.EQ("KeyName", keyName));
var sortBy = SortBy.Ascending("KeyName");
var update = Update.Inc("KeyValue", adjustmentAmount);
var result = collection.FindAndModify(query, sortBy, update, true);

var newValue = result.ModifiedDocument.Elements.Last().Value;
return Int32.Parse(newValue.RawValue.ToString());
```

The problem is that I'm unable to cast result.ModifiedDocument correctly back to a "KeyValueDocument."

When debugging, I can clearly see that all three properties of a KeyValueDocument are there, with correct values.  And I can see the "Elements" collection, the last of which has the property which got incremented.  Falling down to the "RawValue" property of that, ToString, parses into an Int.  Whew!

But... there's gotta be a better way!  I'm using C# and the official 10gen driver.

Please help if you can, Thanks!
Travis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your KeyValueDocument class looks like, but assuming it has KeyName and KeyValue properties you could write it like this:

```
// initialize query, sortBy and update as you proposed
var result = collection.FindAndModify(query, sortBy, update, true);
var modifiedDocument = result.GetModifiedDocumentAs<KeyValueDocument>();
return modifiedDocument.KeyValue; // I'm assuming KeyValue is of type int
```